# Debugging "malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages" with Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, malloc

So my app is now firing "malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages" and I have zero idea as to why, nor do I know how to trace this.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can debug it with Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just disable guard pages in xcode - edit scheme in xcode 4