# Subclassed NSTextField generates memory warnings after user input

Tags: objective-c, macos, malloc, nstextfield

I have implemented a subclassed version of `NSTextField`, which I've called `CustomTextField`, the code for which is below:

```
@interface CustomTextField : NSTextField

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable NSImage *backgroundImage;

@end

@implementation CustomTextField

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setDrawsBackground:NO];

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSImage *backgroundImage = self.backgroundImage;

    [backgroundImage drawInRect:rect fromRect:rect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

I have three instances of this custom text field, which I've set-up in my XIB file. When I run the app, select a text field, type in some text, and hit 'Enter', I get the following output from Xcode:

```
malloc: protecting edges
malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
malloc: nano zone does not support guard pages
malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages
```

My guess is that my subclass implementation is not handling something correctly, but I'm honestly not sure. Does anyone have some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429849/debugging-malloc-purgeable-zone-does-not-support-guard-pages-with-xcode

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
[super awakeFromNib];
```

in your `awakeFromNib` method.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib):

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may
>   call the super implementation at any point during your own
>   awakeFromNib method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion...I gave that a shot, but it looks like I'm still getting those warnings.